# Counting sequences

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Identify the amount $x_n$ of sequences $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ of integers $\;a_i \geq 0,\;\; 1 \leq i \leq n\;\;$ so that $\;\sum_{i=1}^j a_i \geq j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n - 1\;$ and $\;\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = n. \quad x_0$ is set as 1.

Hint: Try to guess the by first identifying the values for small $n$. Additionally you can use [OEIS](http://oeis.org).

---

To recap all this I am looking for sequences with $n$ elements where applies:

- All members are positive integers (including 0)
- The sum of all elements is n
- $\sum_{i=1}^j a_i \geq j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n - 1$

As all members are at least 0, the last one is equal to "$ a_1 \geq j\;$", isn't it?

For $n=2$ the sequences are (1,1) and (2,0). For $n=3$ it's (1,1,1),(3,0,0),(2,1,0),(2,0,1),(1,2,0).

Am I right? Do you have any hint how to find the answer?

Comment: there's also $(2,0,1)$.

Comment: A more usual term for "positive integers (including 0)" is "non-negative integers".

Comment: Do you mean $a_i$ wherever you have $u_i$ (or vice versa)?

Comment: There's also $(1,2,0)$.

Comment: @joriki @Oliver-Bégassat thank you @Chris-Taylor yes, thanks

Comment: @joriki: perhaps Bourbaki uses "positive" and "strictly positive"...???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $a_k$ as the number of steps you go to the right on the $k$-th line of an $n\times n$ square grid. This puts your sequences in bijection with the monotonic paths on an $n\times n$ square grid that don't pass above the diagonal; the number of these paths is the [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) $C_n$.

Comment: Thanks, I now know that I am heading for the Catalan numbers! Unfortunately I don't get your approach - why does the number of the monothonic paths equals the amount of sequences I am looking for? I just don't see the relation..

Comment: @muffel, draw a $3\times3$ grid. Concentrate on the vertices (the points where the gridlines intersect). Start at the lower-left vertex. Go $a_1$ steps to the right; go up to the next level; go $a_2$ steps to the right; go up to the next level; go $a_3$ steps to the right; go up to the next level. You have turned your triple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ into a path from lower left to upper right that only ever goes right and up and never goes above the diagonal. Conversely, any such path give you your kind of triple.

Comment: @Gerry-Myserson just great, thanks!